# Installation error when trying to deploy TeamViewer host via Intune

Tags: teamviewer, intune

I tried to deploy the TeamViewer host via intune following the [official guide](https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/Knowledge-Base-EN/TeamViewer-User-Guide-for-Intune/ta-p/45766#toc-hId--300364612). At first everything seemed fine, installs were pending and now some are still pending but some have gotten an installation error 0x80070667. I researched that error and Microsoft says it maps to ERROR_INVALID_COMMAND_LINE so it looks like there is something wrong with the command line parameters? This got me stumped because I carefully followed the guide and still got this error.

My command line for the host installation msi in Intune is like this:

```
/qn APITOKEN=%YOURAPITOKEN% CUSTOMCONFIGID=%YOURCUSTOMCONFIGID% ASSIGNMENTOPTIONS="--grant-easy-access”
```

And I of course replaced the `%YOURAPITOKEN%` and `%YOURCUSTOMCONFIGID%` with the correct strings from the TeamViewer management console.

What might be the problem? I've tried researching and googling and I've found some indications that others have had the same kind of errors that ended up being caused by the `ASSIGNMENTOPTIONS` parameter. I've not yet tried the deployment without that parameter, because I really need to have the easy access enabled on deployment.

I have also sent a ticket to TeamViewer support about the problem but I have not gotten any answers yet.

P.S. We have the correct licenses in use.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Kind regards,
Tenttu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot more researching, googling, diagnosing and experimenting I found the solution myself by accident. All the official guides and older tips, tricks and forum posts tell you to use `ASSIGNMENTOPTIONS="--grant-easy-access"` but I tried "just for the heck of it" without the quotes so I used `ASSIGNMENTOPTIONS=--grant-easy-access` and it deployed without problems and the easy access/unattended access was enabled and all my host customizations and policies worked like a charm.

I tried the uninstall/redeployment cycle a few times again with and without the `ASSIGNMENTOPTIONS` -parameter and I consistently got the same result every time, so it really seems to be the solution to use the parameter without the quotes.

I got an answer from TeamViewer support just a few minutes ago and wrote to them about my solution and asked them to confirm if that really is how it's supposed to work (instead of some glitch). Still haven't gotten an answer to that but I'm quite sure that it's as intended/designed these days.

**TL;DR**, anyone facing the same problem, try leaving out the quotes in command line from `ASSIGNMENTOPTIONS` parameter and it should work. Example below.

WRONG METHOD: `ASSIGNMENTOPTIONS="--grant-easy-access"`

RIGHT METHOD: `ASSIGNMENTOPTIONS=--grant-easy-access`

**EDIT:**
Just letting you know that I got an answer from TeamViewer and they said the quotes should still work but it seems Intune is truncating the command line and that causes problems. They also said that if it works without the quotes, it should still be fine to use that way also.